# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined at SafeSubscriber._next

Tags: node.js, angular

When i try to use map operator ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined  at SafeSubscriber._next is shown by console. how can i fix this error?

[image]

i use bellow .ts file as a service file of one of the component

```
import { Post } from './post.model';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})

export class PostService{
private posts: Post[] = [];
private postUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

getPosts(){
  this.http.get<{message: string, posts: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts').pipe(map((postData) => {
    return postData.posts.map(post => {
    return {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content,
      id: post._id
    };
    });
  })).subscribe(transformedPost => {
    this.posts = transformedPost.posts;
    this.postUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
  });
}

getPostUpdateListener(){
  return this.postUpdated.asObservable();
}

addPost(title: string, content: string){
const post: Post ={id: null, title: title, content: content };
this.http.post<{message}>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts',post).subscribe((responseData) => {
  console.log(responseData.message);
  this.posts.push(post);
  this.postUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
})


}

}
```

This is the model which i used as Post

```
export interface Post {
  id:string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing incorrect parameters for `http.post`:

```js
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response>
```

If you want to pass headers, you must new to create a new instance of `Headers` and `RequestOptions`:

```js
let headers = new Headers({ id: null, title: title, content: content  });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

Or even simplify the code:

```js
let headers = new Headers({ id, title, content});
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

And then use it:

```js
this.http.post<{message}>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts',options)
```

Also, please check the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) for headers on http requests.